# Unity 5 Client Server Networking - Spawn and manipulate objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, unity-networking, clients

I am working on a Simple Client Server system in Unity 5. I want to use the new HLAPI. But I have some questions. I can't spawn or edit objects, which are spawned on the server. I want to have 1 server, to which 2 clients will connect. On the server I will see the scene and all actions of each client. Then I want to spawn object or manipulate them. How can I do it?

Server and Client setup:

```
public void SetupServer()
{
    NetworkServer.Listen(4444);
    isAtStartup = false;
    serverGUI = true;
}

public void SetupClient()
{
    myClient = new NetworkClient();
    myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);     
    myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);
    isAtStartup = false;
}
```

Then when I want to spawn, for example, a cube with a button, I use this:

```
ClientScene.RegisterPrefab (cube);
GameObject c = Instantiate (cube, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
NetworkServer.Spawn (c);
```

The cube has a NetworkIdentity component.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting the spawn inside a command? ex.
[Command]
CmdSpawnSomething(){
GameObject c = Instantiate (cube, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
NetworkServer.Spawn (c);
}

Comment: Yes, I already did it. There must be a call like the RPC. But i need a NetworkIdentity to perform RPCClients. But these objects arent visual.